# Deploy kubernetes cluster on Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, coreos

I tried to create kubernetes cluster(v1.2.3) on azure with coreos cluster. I followed the documentation (http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/)

Then I cloned the repo( git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes). And I did a minor change in file( docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/cloud_config_templates/kubernetes-cluster-main-nodes-template.yml) changed the kube version from v1.1.2 to v1.2.3.

And then I created the cluster by running the file(./create-kubernetes-cluster.js), cluster is successfully created for me. But in master node API server didn't get started..

I checked the log it was showing - **Cloud provider could not be initialized: unknown cloud provider "vagrant"**.. I could not catch why this issue was coming..

**This is my Log of -> kube-apiserver.service**

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2016-07-23 12:41:36 UTC, end at Sat 2016-07-23 12:44:19 UTC. --

Jul 23 12:43:06 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes API Server.

Jul 23 12:43:06 anudemon-master-00 kube-apiserver[1964]: I0723 12:43:06.299966    1964 server.go:188] Will report 172.16.0.4 as public IP address.

Jul 23 12:43:06 anudemon-master-00 kube-apiserver[1964]: F0723 12:43:06.300057    1964 server.go:211] Cloud provider could not be initialized: unknown cloud provider "vagrant"

Jul 23 12:43:06 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a

Jul 23 12:43:06 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: Unit entered failed state.

Jul 23 12:43:06 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Jul 23 12:43:16 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.

Jul 23 12:43:16 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: Stopped Kubernetes API Server.

Jul 23 12:43:16 anudemon-master-00 kube-apiserver[2015]: I0723 12:43:16.428476    2015 server.go:188] Will report 172.16.0.4 as public IP address.

Jul 23 12:43:16 anudemon-master-00 kube-apiserver[2015]: F0723 12:43:16.428534    2015 server.go:211] Cloud provider could not be initialized: unknown cloud provider "vagrant"

Jul 23 12:43:16 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes API Server.

Jul 23 12:43:16 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a

Jul 23 12:43:16 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: Unit entered failed state.

Jul 23 12:43:16 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Jul 23 12:43:26 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.

Jul 23 12:43:26 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: Stopped Kubernetes API Server.

Jul 23 12:43:26 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes API Server.

Jul 23 12:43:26 anudemon-master-00 kube-apiserver[2024]: I0723 12:43:26.756551    2024 server.go:188] Will report 172.16.0.4 as public IP address.

Jul 23 12:43:26 anudemon-master-00 kube-apiserver[2024]: F0723 12:43:26.756654    2024 server.go:211] Cloud provider could not be initialized: unknown cloud provider "vagrant"

Jul 23 12:43:26 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a

Jul 23 12:43:26 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: Unit entered failed state.

Jul 23 12:43:26 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Jul 23 12:43:36 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.

Jul 23 12:43:36 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: Stopped Kubernetes API Server.

Jul 23 12:43:36 anudemon-master-00 systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes API Server.

Jul 23 12:43:36 anudemon-master-00 kube-apiserver[2039]: I0723 12:43:36.872849    2039 server.go:188] Will report 172.16.0.4 as public IP address.
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at kuberenetes-anywhere (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes-anywhere)? Much work has been done there and now probably has all the right bits to deploy out your cluster with Azure specific cloud provider integrations.